# Javafx. Не работает ComboBox из класса Controller

Tags: java, javafx, gui, checkbox, fxml

Для JavaFX-приложения использую связку: Сontroller.java, Main.java и scene.fxml.
Задача: добавить CheckBox с определенными значениями.
В классе **Controller.java** создаю ObservableList и передаю его созданному ComboBox:

```
ObservableList<String> test = FXCollections.observableArrayList("one", "two", "three", "etc");
@FXML
ComboBox<String> Spots = new ComboBox<>(test);
```

В **scene.fxml** добавлено:

```
<ComboBox fx:id="Spots" layoutX="99.0" layoutY="111.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="65.0" promptText="n"></ComboBox>
```

При запуске выходит пустой список:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если в каком-нибудь обработчике событий, например у кнопки, прописать:

```
Spots.setItems(test);
```

То список значений появляется в созданном ранее CheckBox. Почему список не инициализируется при создании объекта?

PS. Если прописать значения списка непосредственно в **scene.fxml**, то список работает:

```
        <ComboBox fx:id="Spots" layoutX="99.0" layoutY="111.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="65.0" promptText="n">
        <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                <Integer fx:value="1" />
                <Integer fx:value="2" />
                <Integer fx:value="3" />
                <Integer fx:value="4" />
                <Integer fx:value="5" />
                <Integer fx:value="6" />
                <Integer fx:value="7" />
                <Integer fx:value="8" />
                <Integer fx:value="9" />
                <Integer fx:value="10" />
            </FXCollections>
        </items>
    </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FXML` элементы не нужно инициализировать, это за вас делает `FXMLLoader`, иначе вы потеряетя ссылку на объект в сцене; замените

```
@FXML
ComboBox<String> Spots = new ComboBox<>(test);
```

на:

```
@FXML
ComboBox<String> Spots;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
     Spots.setItems( test );
}
```